# Is there any way to rename physical devices paired using wi-fi in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-wifi, android-wireless

One of the recent Android Studio updates introduced ability to connect physical android devices (with android 11+) using wi-fi (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?utm_source=android-studio-2021-1-1#wireless)

The thing is I have several testing devices which appear in the list of devices with their code names as titles, such as `samsung SM-G973F` instead of `samsung galaxy s10`. It's quite confusing how to distinguish them between each other without remembering all these code names while testing the app when several these devices are connected on the same time.

Is there any way to rename physical devices connected using wi-fi in Android Studio?

[image]

[image]